# Upload de xlsx Spring MVC e comparar dados com SQL

Tags: sql, java-ee, spring-mvc

Estou tentando fazer upload de um arquivo xlsx e compará-lo com a minha tabela do banco de dados, porém não estou conseguindo, como meu arquivo é muito grande não consigo lê-lo com o Apache POI e depois comparar com a tabela do SQL.

Vocês conseguem pelo menos me nortear de como fazer esse upload do arquivo e compará-lo.